# I want to call an action class onChange of select tag in struts2

Tags: struts2

I want to call an action class on change of select tag in struts2 without refreshing the form. please guide me. what i am doing. I call a javascript function onChange event where i set the name of action in the form's action attribute and then i call submit of the form.

Comment: You should handle the event by issuing an action url to the server.

Comment: Take a look at the Struts2-jquery-plugin showcase.

Comment: I implemented the Struts2-jquery-plugin showcase in the project and try to populate the second select box based on first select box but could not succeed.